# Identifying gradient direction of edge (inwards\outwards)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, imaging

I am trying to find whether the gradient of an edge is pointing inwards or outwards (out of image) in order to identify tumors. Any ideas on how to do this elegantly?

[boundaries image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8SI5.png)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking here. Your sample image appears to be a binary edge image: green lines of a single intensity on a pure black background. At a minimum, please post a labeled image showing vectors pointed in the direction you want as well as captions for features such as the tumor, organs, etc. It could help to have the original image from which your edge image is derived.

Comment: *Caveat utilitor* - This user has not accepted any answers since he/she has been a member. Tread lightly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I managed to solve it. 
How do you accept answers? I'm a newbie here...

Answer (score 0):

Positive Laplacian Operator

In Positive Laplacian we have standard mask in which center element of the mask should be negative and corner elements of mask should be zero.

```
 Positive Laplacian Operator is use to take out outward edges in an image.
```

Negative Laplacian Operator

In negative Laplacian operator we also have a standard mask, in which center element should be positive. All the elements in the corner should be zero and rest of all the elements in the mask should be -1.

```
 Negative Laplacian operator is use to take out inward edges in an image
```